# Wordpress Docker Image, PHP Fatal error: Out of memory

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, apache, apple-m1

**I m getting above error while i upload the image in the form which is more than 2MB.**

**My Docker file**

```
FROM amd64/wordpress:latest

COPY . /var/www/html
COPY /config-staging /var/www/html
COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php
COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
COPY uploads.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
COPY wordpress.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
COPY custom-php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
COPY custom.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
COPY .user.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
RUN chown -R nobody:nogroup /tmp
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
ENV PORT 80

EXPOSE 80
```

**My INI file for all experiments**

```
file_uploads = On
display_errors = Off
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 512M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.save_path = "/tmp"
upload_max_filesize = 512M
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCehE.png)

**Solutions already tried**

- Added in .htaccess -> php_value upload_max_filesize 512M and php_value memory_limit 512M
- Added in wp.config.php -> define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');

Comment: Since making these config changes, have you rebooted your server / restarted Apache / NGINX?

Comment: Yes i able to figured out this issue it seems to have some backend problem where it App Engine is not taking body more than 32 MB as an FLEX Env. on Nodejs